# AWS VPC Endpoint Service: How to append Principals

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create an AWS VPC Endpoint Service (PrivateLink) where I can add Principals to those that already exist.  Here is my current code

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "privatelink" {
  provider                   = aws.customer
  acceptance_required        = true
  network_load_balancer_arns = ["${aws_lb.nlb.arn}"]
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_service_allowed_principal" "addition" {
  provider                = aws.customer
  vpc_endpoint_service_id = aws_vpc_endpoint_service.privatelink.id
  principal_arn           = var.consumer_principal_arn
}
```

That works great for the one Principal specified in the variable but overwrites the existing Principal when I run it again with a different Principal.  What I want is to *append* zero or more Principals to the list of existing Principals, *each time I do a terraform apply*.  For example, the first time I run it, I specify Principal X.  I run it again, specifying Principal Y.  Now the list of allowed Principals is X and Y.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create multiple `aws_vpc_endpoint_service_allowed_principal` resources with each additional ARN. This way you can revoke principal(s) in the future without destroying other existing associations. Of course you can use [for each loop](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/meta-arguments/count.html) and create `aws_vpc_endpoint_service_allowed_principal` resources with count and a list of principal ARNs. However, if you remove a principal from the list, associations for all the principals after the removed principal from the list will be recreated and the associations needs to be accepted again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the existing resource definition to add another principal. Terraform sees that as an update to the resource named "addition" and performs an update instead. Instead you need to add another `aws_vpc_endpoint_service_allowed_principal` resource.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Mark.  My apologies for not being clear; I have updated the question to reflect the requirement that I want to append zero or more Principals to any existing Principals.

Comment: @PaulWaldo I don't know what that means. How do you append a principal to a principal? What you actually need to do is add a new principal to the list of allowed principals. There is no such thing as appending a principal to another principal.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have clarified.

Comment: @PaulWaldo yes and your clarification doesn't change my answer. You seem to be missing the key point of how Terraform state works. You can't modify an existing resource definition in order to add a new resource to your infrastructure. Terraform will see that as a modification of an existing resource. I suggest you create a map or list of the ARNs you want to allow, and use `for_each` to create them, then you would only have to add a value to the list.